# Karma: Is it possible to load JavaScript files statically before the requirejs framework?

Tags: javascript, testing, knockout.js, requirejs, karma-runner

I'm wondering if it's possible to configure Karma (0.10.9) to load certain JavaScript files before its [requirejs](https://www.npmjs.org/package/karma-requirejs) framework? The reason I'm asking is that Knockout registers as a module with RequireJS if the latter has been included before Knockout, and this breaks another module (which doesn't support RequireJS).

Basically, our karma.conf.js looks as below:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({
        basePath: "Scripts",
        frameworks: ['mocha', 'requirejs'],
        files: [
            "knockout-2.2.1.debug.js",
            "knockout.viewmodel.2.0.3.js",
            {pattern: "test/**/*.js", included: false},
            {pattern: "shared/**/*.js", included: false},
            {pattern: "app/**/*.js", included: false},
        ],
        reporters: ['progress', 'growl'],
        // web server port
        // CLI --port 9876
        port: 9876,
        // cli runner port
        // CLI --runner-port 9100
        runnerPort: 9100,
        autoWatch: true,
        browsers: ["PhantomJS"],
        // If browser does not capture in given timeout [ms], kill it
        // CLI --capture-timeout 5000
        captureTimeout: 5000,
        // Auto run tests on start (when browsers are captured) and exit
        // CLI --single-run --no-single-run
        singleRun: false,
        // report which specs are slower than 500ms
        // CLI --report-slower-than 500
        reportSlowerThan: 500,
        plugins: [
          'karma-mocha',
          'karma-phantomjs-launcher',
          'karma-growl-reporter',
          'karma-requirejs'
        ]
    });
}
```

Comment: See https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/699

Comment: This presentation will give you a quick look at how it could be done: http://believeblog.azurewebsites.net/post/learn-knockoutjs-with-its-father

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently it can be done by manually including karma-requirejs files and not including it among the frameworks:

```
frameworks: ['mocha'],
files: [     
  "knockout-2.2.1.debug.js",
  "knockout.viewmodel.2.0.3.js",
  'node_modules/requirejs/require.js',
  'node_modules/karma-requirejs/lib/adapter.js',
  {pattern: "test/**/*.js", included: false},
  {pattern: "shared/**/*.js", included: false},
  {pattern: "app/**/*.js", included: false}
]
```

See this Karma [issue](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/699) for reference.