# unit testing jquery click event in angular 7

Tags: jquery, angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I've an angular app in which I've a `<a>` tag which looks like this.

```
<a class="add-new-item" href="javascript:void(0);" >Add Item</a>
```

On clicking this link, the application runs a jquery function that dynamically adds some html into the code.

```
  $("body").on("click", ".add-new-item", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var parent = $(this).parent();
    parent.find(".item-wrapper").append(
      $(".menu-item", parent)
        .eq(0)
        .clone(true)
    );
  });
```

I wrote the following test.

```
  it("add new item link should add a new item", () => {
    const elementDe: DebugElement = fixture.debugElement;
    const addNewDe = elementDe.query(By.css(".add-new-item"));
    const newWrapperItem = elementDe.query(By.css(".item-wrapper"));

    expect(newWrapperItem.childNodes.length).toEqual(1);
    addNewDe.nativeElement.click();
    expect(newWrapperItem.childNodes.length).toEqual(2);
  });
```

But this doesn't call the `jquery click event` mentioned above resulting in `Expected 1 to equal 2.` error. Now I am not sure what would be the right way to do this.

Comment: Why are you binding with jQuery rather than `ng-click`, and why are you creating markup with jQuery rather than having angular generate it?

Comment: I am using a theme which was written in javascript and html, I converted the theme into angular with minimum changes. That's why its in javascript.

Comment: Just nitpicking, but you mean in "jQuery".  It's all javascript. :)

Comment: I meant "jQuery".

Comment: Does your unit test have access to jQuery?  I would try changing it to `$(addNewDe.nativeElement).trigger('click')` to force the event creation.  If not, there should be a post some where about generating and dispatching an event in vanilla javascript.

Comment: Its not included but I also don't know how to include it. Can you help out please. I am beginner with unit testing in angular. your approach is not working because jquery is not working.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/u9wvfLt2/  Here's a dummy little example of manually generating a click event and dispatching it, without jQuery

Comment: Not working, I guess I would have to add the javascript files inside karma for it to work. I am looking to include the js files inside karma.config.js now

Answer (score 0):

Solved it,

I had to include the javascript files inside `karma.config.js` for it to function properly.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22228399/karma-is-it-possible-to-load-javascript-files-statically-before-the-requirejs-f) was a good pointer for me to start.